# Group DateTime by year and month then order it

Tags: c#, linq

I have this C# code

```cs
var items = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>()
{
    { "1", new DateTime(2018, 12, 12) }, // year, month, day
    { "2", new DateTime(2018, 12, 10) },
    { "4", new DateTime(2017, 12, 12) },
    { "3", new DateTime(2018, 10, 12) }
};

var groupedItems = items.GroupBy(i => new
{
    i.Value.Year,
    i.Value.Month
});

Console.WriteLine(groupedItems);
```

Which gives me this in [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net)

[image]

I want to sort and order it in a way to obtain this:

```cs
var items = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
{
    {
        "2018/12", new List<string>()
        {
            "1",
            "2"
        }
    },
    {
        "2018/10", new List<string>()
        {
            "3",
        }
    },
    {
        "2017/12", new List<string>()
        {
            "4",
        }
    }
};
```

How can I do that?

I tried using some more `GroupBy` but wasn't really able to achieve what I wanted, I guess I'm too bad at logic

Comment: When you say "looking like this" can you show a C# data structure declaration that represents what you want?

Comment: @NetMage Done ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your example, did you mean something like this:

```
var groupedItems = items
    .OrderByDescending(item => item.Value)
    .GroupBy(i => new
    {
        i.Value.Year,
        i.Value.Month
    })
    .ToDictionary
    (
        group => $"{group.Key.Year}/{group.Key.Month}",
        group => group.Select(item => item.Key).ToList()
    );
```

It's the `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` where `Key` is `year/month` and the value is list of string values belonging within that month of the year.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is almost exactly what I wanted and I updated my example at the same time you posted your answer. I'd like to sort it by date however, how can I do that?

Comment: Right idea, but I don't think he wanted the Key in the list ...

Comment: You could probably order the items by date desc before grouping them. Check the updated answer to see if it works.

Comment: @Jason I did, please see my post example (:

Comment: Ahh ... cool, I started writing the same answer, but you originally mentioned having a Dictionary<string, Date> so I thought you wanted dates :)

@msmolcic beat me to it anyway ...